# How can I use a loop to make this React component more DRY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make an audio mixer using the web audio api. I'm having trouble figuring out how to name the refs. How can I create this component without hard coding every track?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { initialTracks } from "./initialTracks";

function App() {
  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState(initialTracks);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);
  const trackRef0 = useRef();
  const trackRef1 = useRef();
  const trackRef2 = useRef();
  const trackRef3 = useRef();
  const trackRef4 = useRef();
  const trackRef5 = useRef();
  const trackRef6 = useRef();
  const trackRef7 = useRef();
  const trackRef8 = useRef();
  const trackRef9 = useRef();
  const trackRef10 = useRef();
  const trackRef11 = useRef();

  console.log("length", tracks.length);

  useEffect(() => {
    const audioElement0 = trackRef0.current;
    const audioElement1 = trackRef1.current;
    const audioElement2 = trackRef2.current;
    const audioElement3 = trackRef3.current;
    const audioElement4 = trackRef4.current;
    const audioElement5 = trackRef5.current;
    const audioElement6 = trackRef6.current;
    const audioElement7 = trackRef7.current;
    const audioElement8 = trackRef8.current;
    const audioElement9 = trackRef9.current;
    const audioElement10 = trackRef10.current;
    const audioElement11 = trackRef11.current;
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();

    const track0 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement0);
    const track1 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement1);
    const track2 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement2);
    const track3 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement3);
    const track4 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement4);
    const track5 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement5);
    const track6 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement6);
    const track7 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement7);
    const track8 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement8);
    const track9 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement9);
    const track10 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement10);
    const track11 = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement11);

    track0.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track1.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track2.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track3.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track4.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track5.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track6.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track7.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track8.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track9.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track10.connect(audioContext.destination);
    track11.connect(audioContext.destination);
    audioContext.resume();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const audioElement0 = trackRef0.current;
    const audioElement1 = trackRef1.current;
    const audioElement2 = trackRef2.current;
    const audioElement3 = trackRef3.current;
    const audioElement4 = trackRef4.current;
    const audioElement5 = trackRef5.current;
    const audioElement6 = trackRef6.current;
    const audioElement7 = trackRef7.current;
    const audioElement8 = trackRef8.current;
    const audioElement9 = trackRef9.current;
    const audioElement10 = trackRef10.current;
    const audioElement11 = trackRef11.current;

    if (isPlaying) {
      audioElement0.pause();
      audioElement1.pause();
      audioElement2.pause();
      audioElement3.pause();
      audioElement4.pause();
      audioElement5.pause();
      audioElement6.pause();
      audioElement7.pause();
      audioElement8.pause();
      audioElement9.pause();
      audioElement10.pause();
      audioElement11.pause();
    } else {
      audioElement0.play();
      audioElement1.play();
      audioElement2.play();
      audioElement3.play();
      audioElement4.play();
      audioElement5.play();
      audioElement6.play();
      audioElement7.play();
      audioElement8.play();
      audioElement9.play();
      audioElement10.play();
      audioElement11.play();
    }
  }, [isPlaying]);

  const channels = tracks.map((track, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={track.path}>
        <audio ref={trackRef0} src={tracks[0].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef1} src={tracks[1].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef2} src={tracks[2].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef3} src={tracks[3].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef4} src={tracks[4].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef5} src={tracks[5].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef6} src={tracks[6].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef7} src={tracks[7].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef8} src={tracks[8].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef9} src={tracks[9].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef10} src={tracks[10].path}></audio>
        <audio ref={trackRef11} src={tracks[11].path}></audio>
      </div>
    );
  });
  console.log("channels", channels);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Audio Mixer</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>play</button>
      {channels}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hi. I'm trying to make an audio mixer using the web audio api. I'm having trouble figuring out how to name the refs. How can I create this component without hard coding every track?

Answer (score 3):

You only need one ref, the container, and then you can access each child with `.children`. Something along the lines of:

```
function App() {
    const [tracks, setTracks] = useState(initialTracks);
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(true);
    const tracksContainerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        for (const audio of tracksContainerRef.current.children) {
            audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio).connect(audioContext.destination);
        }
        audioContext.resume();
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        for (const audio of tracksContainerRef.current.children) {
            if (isPlaying) {
                audio.pause();
            } else {
                audio.play();
            }
        }
    }, [isPlaying]);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Audio Mixer</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setIsPlaying(!isPlaying)}>play</button>
            <div ref={tracksContainerRef}>
                {
                    tracks.map(({ path }) => <audio src={path} />)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!!